# Wildcard in javascript path

Tags: javascript, jquery, path, wildcard

I need to specify a path with wildcard on the end of an if statement..
like the equivalent of * in the filesystem

```
if(document.location.pathname == "/project/*") { jQuery("#regbutton").css('display','none'); };
```

ie.. the if should fire for all paths that start with /project/

any way to do this w/out resorting to wild regex stuff?
jquery solution would be great too..

thnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This uses a regex, but it's about as tame as regexes get.

```
if(document.location.pathname.match(/^\/project\//))
{
    jQuery("#regbutton").css('display','none');
}
```

Comment: works smooth as silk.. many thanx  ( that really is non-scary regex :)

Comment: @Joseph: I have edited my answer; I forgot that you don't need to call `toString()` on `location.pathname` (since it's already a string) [though you _would_ need to call `toString()` on the `location` itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Use_as_a_string).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:-

```
String.prototype.startsWith = function(str) {return (this.match("^"+str)==str)}

if(document.location.pathname.startsWith("/project/")) {
   ...
}
```

This way, you can keep using startsWith() function anytime you want next time.

Comment: have not tried this yet but I will .. I like the reusable idea, thank you